# Referrer header not found error while calling http requests from node.js

Tags: node.js, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I am getting the error **"message": "Referrer header not found** while calling the http request from the node.js server.

The requirement is like, first I need to hit a box which accepts only the ajax requests and then route to the actual service.

Snapshot of the code

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://' + fullpath,
    qs : params,
    headers : {
        Cookie : "COOKIE=" + my_cookie,
        Origin: 'http://my_url',
        "X-Requested-With": 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    encoding : null,

};


request.get(options, function (err, response, body) {

}
```

Any thoughts on the above error ?

Thnx

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing a `Referer` header to `request.get` and apparently the server at `http://[fullpath]` expects it (perhaps as a sort of misguided form of security).

Try adding one:

```
headers : {
    Cookie : "COOKIE=" + my_cookie,
    Origin: 'http://my_url',
    "X-Requested-With": 'XMLHttpRequest',
    Referer : 'http://' + fullpath
},
```